# How do you use text fields as an input in Java GUI to set RGB values?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, colors, rgb

I have this code so far where I would like the text fields I have created to be able to take in input for RGB values and then when the 'Change Colour' button is pressed a message will appear on the Frame in the colour that had been specified in the text fields e.g. if the values of the text fields were red: 255, blue: 0, green: 0, that colour would be the colour of the text.

I am fairly new to java so any help on how I could possibly get started with this would be appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {



    FilledFrame frame = new FilledFrame(); // Create new JFrame
    frame.setVisible( true ); // Set it to visible
    frame.setSize(500, 500); // Set size of JFrame window
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Set default close operation
    frame.setTitle("Change Colour"); // Set title of the JFrame window


}
}

class FilledFrame extends JFrame {

public FilledFrame()
{
    JButton mainButton = new JButton("Change Color"); // Create new button
    JPanel Panel = new JPanel(); // Create JPanel for the button

    Panel.add(mainButton); // Add button to the JFrame
    add(Panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // Set layout of the button to bottom of the window

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome"); // Create the welcome message
    JPanel Panel1 = new JPanel(); // Create JPanel for the label

    Panel1.add(label); // Add label to the frame
    add(Panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER); // Set layout of the label to centre
    label.setForeground(Color.BLUE); // Set color of the label to blue

    Label red, green, blue;
    TextField redT, greenT, blueT;

    red = new Label("Red"); // Create label Red
    green = new Label("Green"); // Create Label Green
    blue = new Label("Blue"); // Create Label Blue

    redT = new TextField(5); // Create text field for input for red value
    greenT = new TextField(5); // Create text field for input green value
    blueT = new TextField(5); // Create text field for input blue value

    // Add the labels and text fields to the frame window

    Panel.add(red);
    Panel.add(redT);
    Panel.add(blue);
    Panel.add(blueT);
    Panel.add(green);
    Panel.add(greenT);

    add(Panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // Set position of the labels and text fields at bottom of the window
}
```

}

Comment: If you are really bent on using JTextFields for entering RGB values from 0 to 255 then I suppose you can create a [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) to do so and apply it to each JTextField. You can create a filter to only allow digits to be entered and only accept a value from  0 to 255 if you like. Easier just to use the JSpinner as already mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some are correct. Others are not. Be consistent.
2. Don't use "Label" and "TextField". Those are AWT components. In a Swing application you should be using `JLabel` and `JTextField`.
3. You may want to consider using a `JSpinner` as it can be configured to make sure you only enter digits in the range 0 - 255. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Spinners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

> when the 'Change Colour' button is pressed

Then you need to add an ActionListener to the button. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for a working example to get you started.

Then in the ActionListener you get the values from the spinner

```
int red = (Integer)redSpinner.getValue();
int green = (Integer)greenSpinner.getValue();
int blue = (Integer)blueSpinner.getValue();
Color color = new Color(red, green, blue);
label.setForeground( color );
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, In regards to the JSpinner would I replace the 3 JTextFields with the JSpinner or create 3 new JSpinner variables?

Comment: @Virdee, The spinner takes the place of the text field. It is now the component that gets the users input.

Comment: How would I write that out as I have looked through the tutorial you provided on Spinners however I'm still unsure would I just do something like 'JSpinner redSpinner = new JSpinner'? and then add that to the panel?

Comment: What do you mean you are unsure? The tutorial contains working examples. What part of the tutorial don't you understand. Ask a specific question. A JSpinner is no different that a JTextField. It is just a component you add to a panel. The only difference is you need to tell the spinner to use a number model, like the tutorial does for the "Year" spinner. This way you can make sure the user only enters numbers in your defined range.